# JQuery $.get returns object

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I'm new to using JQuery, and I'm having a problem with this line of code.

```
function getById(id, callback) 
{
  return  $.get(url, {}, callback);
}
```

When i look at what .get returns it's not an xml node or JSON which is what I thought it was supposed to return. Instead I get an Object with a collection of Methods and Prototype. Also it has a ready state. So its not returning undefined but its also not returning what I'd expect. what could the problem be?

I've tried assigning the get to a variable but that didn't do anything I also tried using a callback function but I don't really understand how I can use that to assign the data returned from get to a variable.

Comment: Short answer: The "A" in AJAX stands for "asynchronous."  This means that the `.get()` function *returns* before the AJAX call *completes*.  The result of the AJAX call will be available in the `callback` function.  Long answer: The question has been duplicated *many times*.  See the referenced question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

It allows you to use the eventual result of the asynchronous operation.
Call the `then()` method and pass a callback to run code when the response arrives.
This returns a new promise of the result of that code.

Comment: so in this example, from getByID response, you can call then? var test = getByID(1); test.then( function(res){ console.log(res) } )

Answer (score 1):

The `$.ajax()` functions return a `jqXHR` object. The data returned from the ajax call will be passed to your callback, or to the `done` callback of the `jqXHR` object.

I would recommend reading the [`$.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and the [ajax category](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/) of the learning site.

Answer (score 0):

It return [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). As AJAX is asynchronous you can't just return `$.get` method.

So you need to use your callback method:

```
$.get(url, {}, function( data ) {
    console.log( 'data' );
});
```